Three rectangular axes are rotated about given line
If three rectangular axes are rotated about the line given by:
$$x/l=y/m=z/n$$
into new positions and the direction cosines of the new axes referred to the old are $l_1$, $m_1$, $n_1$ ; $l_2$, $m_2$, $n_2$ ; $l_3$, $m_3$, $n_3$; and if
$$l_1 = \pm (m_2n_3-m_3n_2)$$,
then show that
$$l(m_3\pm n_2) = m(n_1 + l_3) = n(l_2 + m_1)$$

What have you tried?

So I tried writing a point in first system at unit distance as (l,m,n). Then I applied transformation on the coordinates. I make the assumption that the point should still be (l,m,n) in new system. However, not able to proceed from there
